# Is there a way to use jQueryUI sortable on table with hidden columns

Tags: jquery-ui, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

Recently I had to fix a strange behaviour on a table which use jQueryUI sortable on rows.

When I drag and move a row, the table is shrinked.

After some research, I was able te reproduce the behaviour on simple table :

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/bdesprez_thalassa/eoxdtjn1/10/)

```css
#sort2 .hidden {
  display: none;
}
.fullsize {
  width: 100%;
}
.fix30 {
  width: 30px;
}
    
.fix100 {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
    <html>
      <body>
      <table id="sort1" class="fullsize">
      <thead><tr>
        <th class="hidden">hide</th>
        <th class="hidden">hide</th>
        <th class="hidden">hide</th>
        <th class="fix30">Test1</th>
        <th>Test2</th>
        <th class="fix100">Test3</th>
        <th class="fix100">Test4</th>
        <th class="fix100">Test5</th>
      </tr></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="hidden">hide</td>
          <td class="hidden">hide</td>
          <td class="hidden">hide</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="hidden">hide</td>
          <td class="hidden">hide</td>
          <td class="hidden">hide</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="hidden">hide</td>
          <td class="hidden">hide</td>
          <td class="hidden">hide</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      
      <hr />
      
        <table id="sort2" class="fullsize">
      <thead><tr>
        <th class="hidden">hide</th>
        <th class="hidden">hide</th>
        <th class="hidden">hide</th>
        <th class="fix30">Test1</th>
        <th>Test2</th>
        <th class="fix100">Test3</th>
        <th class="fix100">Test4</th>
        <th class="fix100">Test5</th>
      </tr></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="hidden">hide</td>
          <td class="hidden">hide</td>
          <td class="hidden">hide</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="hidden">hide</td>
          <td class="hidden">hide</td>
          <td class="hidden">hide</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="hidden">hide</td>
          <td class="hidden">hide</td>
          <td class="hidden">hide</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      
      </body>
    </html>
```

```js
    var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
        var $originals = tr.children();
        var $helper = tr.clone();
        $helper.children().each(function(index)
        {
          $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
        });
        return $helper;
    };
    
    $("tbody").sortable({
        helper: fixHelperModified 
        
    }).disableSelection();
```

My guess, when some columns are hidden, the navigator thinks there is more cols in the row compared to the one in the header.

My question : does anyone had the same issue and how to fix it ?

Comment: The movement of the body items is effecting the head items. I cannot observe a change, yet I do see them render different sizes. Trying to inspect each as I move them, but can't see anything change. Did you not want to use DataTables?

Comment: @Twisty : The exemple is just the way I found to reproduce the problem.
I have to figure out how to solve it because it happens in a much larger app which I work on. It is why I can't use DataTables.
My question was, why the table shrink when some cols are hidden and is it possible to fix it.

Comment: Not been able to deduce the issue yet. Are the hidden columns needed?

Comment: @Twisty Yes there are … But it is not the problem … If I delete the cause of the problem of course there won't be the problem … It is not very helpfull lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by modifying you JS a bit, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/GuyNachshon/boh6mwcL/) is what I did:

```
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();
    $helper.children().each(function(index)
    {
      $(this).outerWidth($originals.eq(index).outerWidth())
    });
    
    return $helper;
};

$("tbody").sortable({
  start: function(event, ui) {
    ui.helper.css('display', 'table')
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    ui.item.css('display', '')
  },

    helper: fixHelperModified ,
    start: function(event, ui) {
    return ui.placeholder.children().each(function(index, child) {
      var source;
      source = ui.helper.children().eq(index);
      $(child).removeAttr('class').removeAttr('colspan');
      $(child).addClass(source.attr('class'));
      if (source.attr('colspan')) {
        return $(child).attr('colspan', source.attr('colspan'));
      }
    });
  }
    
}).disableSelection();
```

---

this problem happens because you have a hidden cell (and in the placeholder that the sortable creates for you there are 8 cells and non of them are hidden

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot. I still think it should be fix by the jQueryUI team, but the project is not really maintained anymore ! You arned your bounty :)